# Replace values from dataframe where vector values match indexes in another dataframe

Tags: r, vector, indexing, match, matching

Perhaps the question and answer are already posted, but I can't find it. Besides, is there any optimal approach to this problem?
Because this is just an example of some rows, but I'll apply it to a data frame of about 1 million rows.

I'm kind of new to R.

I have two data frames

```
DF1:
   a b
1  1 0
2  2 0
3  2 0
4  3 0
5  5 0
```

and

```
DF2
  l
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 E
```

What I try to do, is to match the values in DF1$a with the indexes of DF2 and assign those values to DF1$b so my result would be the following way.

```
DF1:
   a b
1  1 A
2  2 B
3  2 B
4  3 C
5  5 E
```

I've coded a for loop to do this, but it seems that I'm missing something

```
for(i in 1:length(df1$a)){
  df1$b[i] <- df2$l[df1$a[i]]
}
```

Which throws the following result:

```
DF1:
   a b
1  1 1
2  2 2
3  2 2
4  3 3
5  5 5
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Indexing is vectorized in R. Just try `df1$b<- df2$l[df1$a]`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `merge` to merge two data frame based on row id and `a`.

```
# Create example data frame
DF1 <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 5))
DF2 <- data.frame(l = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Create a column called a in DF2 shows the row id
DF2$a <- row.names(DF2)

# Merge DF1 and DF2 by a
DF3 <- merge(DF1, DF2, by = "a", all.x = TRUE)

# Change the name of column l to be b
names(DF3) <- c("a", "b")

DF3
#   a b
# 1 1 A
# 2 2 B
# 3 2 B
# 4 3 C
# 5 5 E
```